# How to add config files to a dependency jar to create target executable jar using maven

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-boot-maven-plugin, maven-dependency-plugin

I need to create a "wrapper" project with a pom that pulls in a dependency jar file and adds some local config files to it (form src/main/resources) to create the target jar.

Can this be done using spring-boot-maven-plugin, maven-dependency-plugin, a combination of the two, or some other plugin entirely?   (I have to use maven)

An example pom would be much appreciated.

Note: the dependency jar is built by a 3rd party as an executable jar (with transitive dependencies included) using spring-boot-maven-plugin.  Likewise the jar I build must have the same main class and include all dependencies contained within the 3rd party jar.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to build this wrapper jar? What should it change with respect to the "original" spring boot jar?

Comment: To bundle our site-specific properties files with it.   This will be a microservice that has to be deployed in the same way as our other microservices, with all dependencies and properties files bundled into a single executable jar for each service.

Comment: First in general it's a bad idea to put configuration etc. within the resulting jar it should be provided from outside in microservice world. apart from that put them into `src/main/resources` as any other `application.propertes` etc. and they will being packaged into the resulting jar file...

Comment: A slight correction to what I said above.  *Some* configuration files will be bundled inside the jar.  Others (containing environment specific settings) will be maintained externally.  My question pertains to the former.  I want to create a pom to take a 3rd party dependency jar and add some additional files to it from src/main/resources to create the target jar.  Can this be easily done using maven?